# Trait 'App\HasRoles' not found error in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, roles

I"m try to role permission system by laravel 5.6

when i try to register with default auth(php artisan make:auth) i get this error

> "Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
>   (E_UNKNOWN) Trait 'App\HasRoles' not found"

this my model user.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use HasRoles;

    protected $guard_name = 'web'; 

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you're using the Spatie Laravel Permission package.

If so, you need to import the class like so:

`use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;`

Comment: thanks it's work fine i"m very new to this spatie package

Answer (score 3):

Run this command

> composer install

Answer (score 2):

The line use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles in your code requires the Spatie/Laravel-permission package included to work.

Steps

1. Run 'composer require spatie/laravel-permission'
2. Run composer install

Then your code should work

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Import HasRoles package as follow;

```
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
```

Answer (score 1):

The trait wasn't imported for use. If you are using PhpStorm, like me, click on HasRoles, then hold `alt` key and tap `enter`, choose `import` hit `enter` key and the trait will be imported. You can use these shortcuts to do other imports, for instance, importing models.

Answer (score 0):

*composer require spatie/laravel-permission*    install this composer then it will be work. because you have copied laravel files but not all so install this. it has worked with my project